# To template or not template? (Image class)

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following use case.

I need to create an Image class. An image is defined by:

- the number of pixels (width * height),
- the pixel type (char, short, float, double)
- the number of channels (single channel, 3 channels (RGB), 4 channels (RGBA)

All combinations of the above types shall be possible.

Furthermore,

- I have some algorithms that operate over those images. These algorithms use templates for the pixel type.
- I need to interface with totally generic file formats (e.g. TIFF). In these file formats, the pixel data is saved as a binary stream.

My question is the following: should I use a templated `Image` class, or a generic interface? Example:

```
// 'Generic' Image interface
class Image {
  ...
  protected:
    // Totally generic data container
    uint8_t* data;
};


// Template Image interface
template <typename PixelType>
class Image {
  ...
  protected:
    // Template data container
    PixelType* data;
};
```

**Using Template `Image` Class**

My problem now is that, if I use the templated `Image`class, my file Input/Output will be messy, as when I open an Image file, I don't know a-priori what the Image type will be, so I don't know what template type to return.

This would probably be the optimal solution, if I could figure out a way of creating a generic function that would read an Image from a file and return a generic object, something similar to

```
ImageType load(const char* filename);
```

but since `ImageType` would have to be a template, I don't know how and if I could do this.

**Using Generic `Image` Class**

However, if I use a generic `Image` class, all my algorithms will need a wrapper function with a if/switch statement like:

```
Image applyAlgorithmWrapper(const Image& source, Arguments args) { 

  if (source.channels() == 1) {

    if      (source.type() == IMAGE_TYPE_UCHAR) {
      return FilterFunction<unsigned char>(source, args);
    } 
    else if (source.type() == IMAGE_TYPE_FLOAT) {
      return FilterFunction<float>(source, args);
    } else if ...

  } else if (source.channels() == 3) {

    if      (source.type() == IMAGE_TYPE_UCHAR) {
      return FilterFunction<Vec3b>(source, args);
    }
    ...
  }
```

(NOTE: `Vec3b` is a generic 3 byte structure like

```
struct Vec3b {
  char r, g, b; 
};
```

Comment: The OpenCV library (a very popular library in the computer vision community) uses the generic class. I don't say it's the correct solution, but it's worth taking into account the approach of a widely accepted library.

Comment: From your code I can't see the format of your algorithms, the only solution I can think of instead of templates would be function pointers wrapped in std::function<*return type()*>... You could use std::bind to bind the pointers with their respective class objects....

Comment: You can still provide both with a generic with forward to the templated version. The generic version have so some kind of `std::variant` of your template classes.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion a templated class is the preferred solution.

It will offer you all the advantages of templates which basically mean that your codebase would be cleaner and simpler to understand and maintain.

What you say is a problem when using a templated class is not much of a problem. When a user would like to read an image, he/she should know the data type in which he/she would like to receive the output of the image file. Hence, a user should do it like this :

```
Image<float>* img;
LoadFromTIFF(*img, <filename>);
```

This is very similar to the way it is done in libraries such as ITK. In your module which you will perhaps write to read from TIFF module, you will perform this type-casting to ensure that you return the type that has been declared by the user.

When manually creating an image, the user should do something like :

```
Image<float>*img;
img->SetSize(<width>, <height>);
img->SetChannels(<enum_channel_type>);
```

It is all much simpler in the long run than having a non-templated class.

You could take a look at the source code of [ITK](https://itk.org) to get an idea of how this can be implemented in the most generic sense, as ITK is a highly templated library.

**EDIT (Addendum)**
If you do not want the user to have apriori control over the image data type, you should consider using SMinSampleValue and SMaxSampleValue tags in the TIFF header. These headers are there in any modern TIFF file (Version 6.0). They are intended to have a TYPE that matches the sample datatype in the TIFF file. That I believe would solve your problem

Comment: Actually I have no control over the imported image type. It might be float, double, char, so I cannot instantiate an object before I have that information from the input file

Comment: I do not fully agree with "templates make the codebase simpler and clearner and easier to understand", while sometimes it can be true, but sometimes abused/blind usage of templates can result in completely bloated systems. I think the truth is much more subtle than that.

Comment: @BrunoLevy : I agree with you. My answer did not assume the superiority of templates in an absolute sense.

Comment: Thanks for the addendum. But I can already infer the type AFTER I already opened the file, hence the function was already called. So I can only infer the template types after the file has been open.. And after that, to return an image, in the best case I need an if/switch statement for the return type.

Answer (score 1):

To make the right decision (based on facts rather than opinion) about template versus non-template, my strategy is to *measure* and *compare* for both solutions (templates and non-templates). I like to measure the following indicators:

- number of lines of code
- performances
- compilation time

as well as other more subjective measures such as:

- ease of maintenance
- how much time does it take to a freshman to understand the code

I developed a quite large software [1], and based on these measures, my image class is not a template. I know other imaging library that offers both options [2] (but I do not know what mechanisms they have for that / whether the code remains very legible). I also had some algorithms operating with points of various dimensions (2d, 3d, ... nd), and for these ones making the algorithm a template resulted in a performance gain that made it worth it.

In short, to make the right decision, have clear criteria, clear way of measuring them, and try both options on a toy example.

[1] http://alice.loria.fr/software/graphite/doc/html/

[2] http://opencv.org/

Comment: I think OpenCV offers both templated and non-templated `cv::Mat` versions, which may introduce some clutter to the interface. I don't know yet how they do that, but I guess they have a templated wrapper (`cv::Mat_` ? )

Answer (score 1):

Templates. And a variant. And an 'interface helper', if you don't yet have C++14. Let me explain.

Whenever you have a limited set of specializations for a given operation, you can model them as classes satisfying an interface *or concept*. If these can be expressed as one template class, then do so. It helps your users when they only want a given specialization and all you need is a factory when you read from untyped source (e.g. file). Note that you need a factory *anyway*, it's just that the return type is well-defined normally. And this is where we come to...

Variants. Whenever you don't know your return type, but you know *at compile time* the set of possible return types, use a variant. Typedef your variant so it 'looks like' a base class (note that there no inheritance or virtual functions involved), then use a visitor. A particularly easy way to write a visitor in C++14 is a generic lambda that captures everything by reference. In essence, from that point in your code, you have the specific type. Therefore, take the specific/templated classes as function arguments.

Now, a `boost::variant<>` (or `std::variant<>` if you have it) cannot have member functions. Either you reside to 'C-API style' generic functions (that are possibly just delegating to the member functions) *and* symmetric operators; or you have a helper class that's created from your variant type. If your CR allows it, you might descend from variant - note, some consider this terrible style, others accept it as the library writer's intention (because, had the writers wanted to forbid inheritance, they had written `final`).

Code sketch, do not try to compile:

```
enum PixelFormatEnum { eUChar, eVec3d, eDouble };

template<PixelFormatEnum>
struct PixelFormat;

template<>
struct PixelFormat<eUChar>
{
    typedef unsigned char type;
};
// ...

template<PixelFormatEnum pf>
using PixelFormat_t = typename PixelFormat<pf>::type;

template<PixelFormatEnum pf>
struct Image
{
    std::vector<std::vector<PixelFormat_t<pf> > > pixels; // or anything like that
    // ...
};

typedef boost::variant< Image<eUChar>, Image<eVec3d>, Image<eDouble> > ImageVariant;

template<typename F>
struct WithImageV : boost::static_visitor<void>
{
    // you could do this better, e.g. with compose(f, bsv<void>), but...
    F f_;

    template<PixelFormatEnum e>
    void operator()(const Image<e>& img)
    {
        f_(img);
    }
}

template<typename F>
void WithImage(const ImageVariant& imgv, F&& f)
{
    WithImageV v{f};
    boost::apply_visitor(v, img);
}

std::experimental::optional<ImageVariant> ImageFactory(std::istream& is)
{
    switch (read_pixel_format(is))
    {
    case eUChar: return Image<eUchar>(is);
    // ...
    default: return std::experimental::nullopt;
    }
}

struct MyFavoritePixelOp : public boost::static_visitor<int>
{
    template<PixelFormatEnum e>
    int operator()(PixelFormat_t<e> pixel) { return pixel; }

    template<>
    int operator()(PixelFormat_t<eVec3d> pixel) { return pixel.r + pixel.g + pixel.b; }
};

int f_for_variant(const ImageVariant& imgv)
{
    // this is slooooow. Use it only if you have to, e.g., for loading.
    // Move the apply_visitor out of the loop whenever you can (here you could).
    int sum = 0;
    for (auto&& row : imgv.pixels)
       for (auto&& pixel : row)
           sum += boost::apply_visitor(MyFavoritePixelOp(), pixel);
    return sum;
}

template<PixelTypeEnum e>
int f_for_type(const Image<e>& img)
{
    // this is faster
    int sum = 0;
    for (auto&& row : img)
       for (auto&& pixel : row)
           sum += MyFavoritePixelOp()(pixel);
    return sum;        
}

int main() {
    // ...
    if (auto imgvOpt = ImageFactory(is))
    {
        // 1 - variant
        int res = f_for_variant(*imgvOpt);
        std::cout << res;

        // 2 - template
        WithImage(*imgvOpt, [&](auto&& img) {
           int res2 = f_for_type(img);
           std::cout << res2;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This sounds the best approach. May I abuse your goodwill and ask for detailed examples/references? Or even a book on the subject?

Comment: Added some code above, let me know if it works or you have questions on it.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the example! Despite not having boost nor C++17 available in my project, I understand your point. I don't have a visitor pattern, but I already have template iterators for my Image class. Since this is designed to deal with huge images (100k pixel+) , I think a visitor pattern would introduce high overhead, is this correct?

Comment: @manatttta: quite the contrary! You should do the visitation on _Image<>_, not on _PixelFormat<>_. Once you've got the right Image<> class, you don't need to visit each pixel anymore - e.g., f_for_type()'s MyFavouritePixelOp()(pixel) can be inlined. Of course this means that PixelFormat<> types should provide the same interface (not necessarily member fns, you can also have non-member fns specialized for each PixelFormat<> type). It's actually the fastest possible method, faster than virtuals, faster than switch. Cons? Compiled code size triples, but I don't think that's an issue here.

Comment: @manatttta: W/o boost, you can use the classical (virtual fn-based) visitor pattern. Or roll your own - it's really just a `switch(currentType)` and a `union`. Lack of auto lambdas (gcc4.9+, C++17) means you need to cut the code (introduce a new templated function/member function with the body that you'd normally write to the lambda) on the barrier where you deserialize the image and at each virtual fn where you pass the image. If you can avoid virtuals in most places, that's a no-issue essentially.